# why I can't change color of caret in select element

Tags: html, css

I have problem with changing color of caret in select element.

I tried to insert  element caret from github library but thats can't display, because option tag not support other html elements.

Also I added in css

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
        -moz-appearance:none;
        appearance:none;
```

How can I add caret without inserting image

HTML

```
<select class="selectlokacija">

                      <option value="volvo">Choose option <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down location"></i></span></option>
                      <option value="saab">2002</option>
                      <option value="mercedes">2005</option>
                      <option value="audi">2008</option>
                    </select>
```

CSS

```
.selectlokacija{
width:230px;
padding:10px;
color:white;
background-color:#3E6373;
font-size:15px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-appearance:none;
        -moz-appearance:none;
        appearance:none;

}
```

Comment: where you want to add caret icon ? on the drop down or in the dropdown item ?

Comment: typically every browser have different behavior, so would be good if you create image. check the DEMO. http://jsbin.com/juliceyoxa/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I want to add in dropdown, but I can't to add image

Comment: If I add image, I can't set background color

Comment: @IgorSimic I've shared a DEMO which not required any image, just used a simple `pseudo element`. Here is the demo. http://jsbin.com/juliceyoxa/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct

you can use background image for select input as shown below

fiddled [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/2Lvngz3p/1/)

***code***

**HTML**

```
<select class="selectlokacija">
    <option value="volvo">Choose option</option>
    <option value="saab">2002</option>
    <option value="mercedes">2005</option>
    <option value="audi">2008</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.selectlokacija {
    width:230px;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#3E6373 url("http://s6.postimg.org/yzxyb2kv1/arrow.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;

}
```

hope this will work

Comment: @IgorSimic refer the link and upvote http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13390/when-you-accept-an-answer-should-you-also-vote-it-up  :)

Comment: also you my question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a picture you can create a css caret like this.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

To add it on the place of the original select caret you will have to wrap both of them position relative tag and set a position absolute for the arrow.